# Registration Form not submitting in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I am doing registration in django using a form with overriding save method. I am not having any error but not submitting form. Following is my code:
Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User) 
    meta_keywords=models.CharField("Meta Keywords",max_length=255,
            help_text="Comma delimited set of keywords of meta tag")
    meta_description=models.CharField("Meta Description",max_length=255,
            help_text='Content for description meta tag')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "User Profile for: "+self.username

    class Meta:
        ordering=['-id']
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile
from pprint import pprint


class RegisterationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    fullname = forms.CharField(label = "Full name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "fullname", "email", )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        first_name, last_name = self.cleaned_data["fullname"].split()
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from accounts.forms import RegisterationForm
#from accounts.forms import UserProfile

def register(request,template_name="account/register.html"):
    if request.method=='POST':
        postdata=request.POST.copy()
        form=RegisterationForm(postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            un=postdata.get('username','')
            pw=postdata.get('password','')
            from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate
            new_user=authenticate(username=un,password=pw)
            if new_user and new_user.is_active:
                login(request,new_user)
                url=urlresolvers.reverse('dashboard')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)            
    else:
        form=RegisterationForm()
    page_title="User Registration"
    return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    pass

@login_required
def settings(request):
    pass
```

templatefile(register.html):

```
    <div class="register_form">
    <form method="post" action="." class="cart"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" alt="Register" />
    </form>
</div>
```

After submitting form, it doesn't show any thing except the form again. In db no new records are inserted, I also checked it from admin panel.

I am wondering that what can be the problem because every thing seems fine. Is there some good way to debug problem? some thing like pprint some thing but where to and how to debug in this situation?

Comment: one of the best feature of django is its modularity, there is many pre-built django modules that handles registration. One of the most commonly used is django-registration; another module is Pinax which integrates many commonly used element, including registration.

Comment: @LieRyan thanks for suggestion, registration will be diff. in my case

Comment: from what I've seen so far, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly unique about your current registration flow. And even if you'll be adding a unique flow later on, it's generally easier to use an existing module and extend their functionalities.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes I you are right, the basic stuff for user registration is if available then I should have look on it, I want to know that what is easy to integrate in my system with more better features and better in terms of code, Pinax or django-registration?

Comment: Pinax comes with (much) more out-of-the-box, it comes with not only registrations, but many other niceties (check the Pinax site for full list). I'd recommend Pinax if you're starting a new project or is willing to restart the project. However, since you seem to be integrating registration to an existing site, django-registration may be less intrusive.

Comment: I would stay away from Pinax. The project is pretty inactive, and they are moving from a project-based, to module-based development. I am using Pinax, and I can say it has many nice features, but definitely not very flexible. You can adopt some of the modules and write your own.

Comment: @CppLearner Yes , I think you are right, for such small tasks one need to modify his/her own code instead of getting other things in, I tried django-registration app but it wasn't as flexible and in case of my own code I was able to do those things in my own code without restriction of calling some parent methods e.t.c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me take a wild guess

```
form.save
```

to

```
form.save()
```

I am nervous! Prove me right!!! (or partially right)

Whether I am right or wrong, I usually use Python's `traceback` module. It's really simple to use.

http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html